# Closed form for a markov chain, where transition probabilities depend on $n$?

Tags: probability, markov-process

Let $A_n$ be an event whose success probability $P(A_n)$ depends on the size, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, of a given sample.

Let $d$ be a fixed positive integer.

For the problem I am working on I can assume a sequential sample and derive  - via a geometric argument - the following recurrence relation:
$$ P(A_{n+1}) = P(A_{n+1}|A_n)P(A_{n}) + P(A_{n+1}|A_{n}^c)P(A_{n}^c)\\
 = P(A_{n}) + 2^{-n}(1 - P(A_{n}))$$
with the initial conditions $P(A_d) =0$, $P(A_{d+1}) = 2^{-d}$.

I am interested in whether it is possible to obtain a simple closed form expression for $P(A_n) = P(A_{d+k})$?

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks! Typo - now fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a_{n+1} = \log(1 - \Pr(A_{n+1}))$ for $n=d, d+1, \ldots.$  In these terms the recurrence reads

$$\begin{aligned}
a_{n+1} &= \log(1 - [\Pr(A_n) + 2^{-n}(1 - \Pr(A_n))])\\
&= \log((1-2^{-n})(1 - \Pr(A_n))\\
&= \log(1 - 2^{-n}) + \log(1-\Pr(A_n)) \\
&= \log(1 - 2^{-n}) + a_n
\end{aligned}$$

with initial condition $a_{d+1} = \log(1 - 2^{-d}).$

An easy induction now gives

$$\begin{aligned}
a_{n+d} &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \log\left(1 - 2^{-(d+i)}\right) + a_{d+1}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \log\left(1 - 2^{-(d+i)}\right).
\end{aligned}$$

Returning to the original formulation,

$$\Pr(A_{n+d}) = 1 - \exp(a_{n+d}) = 1 - \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(1 - q^{-(d+i)}\right)= 1 - \prod_{k=d}^{n+d-1} \left(1 - q^{-k}\right)$$

where $q=1/2.$  Using the conventional notation for [q-numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient)

$$[k]_q = \frac{1 - q^k}{1-q} = 1 + q + q^2+ \cdots + q^{k-1}$$

we may write this as

> $$\Pr(A_{n+d}) = 1 - 2^{-n}\prod_{k=d}^{n+d-1} [k]_{1/2} = 1 - 2^{-n}\binom{n+d-1}{n}_{1/2}\,[n]_{1/2}!$$

where the $q$ analogs to the Binomial coefficients and factorials are the *Gaussian Binomial coefficients*

$$\binom{m}{r}_q = \frac{[m]_q [m-1]_q \cdots [m-r+1]_q}{[r]_q [r-1]_q \cdots [2]_q [1]_q}$$

and their related factorials

$$[k]_q! = [k]_q [k-1]_q \cdots [2]_q [1]_q.$$

I believe this won't simplify further, but clearly the product converges rapidly and therefore is straightforward to compute and analyze.  In particular, these $q$-numbers have combinatorial interpretations (closely related to sampling without replacement) and enjoy many [beautiful mathematical properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#Properties) that can help with that analysis.

Comment: (+1) Those [q-analogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog) have got me thinking about other problems in discrete optimization.

Comment: @DifferentialPleiometry I was able to answer so quickly because I have recently been thinking about such problems too.  The relationships with sampling without replacement are much stronger than one might guess from the (limited) Wikipedia article I linked to.

Comment: @whuber (+1) Thanks. One thing I love about this site is frequently when one asks a question the answer is much better than one had any right to expect. Your answer suggests a generalization of my problem is within grasp. PS very minor typo with $q = 1/2$ I think those exponents should be positive?

Comment: I appreciate your sharp eyes, Bob.  However, before posting this answer I tested the formula against a direct calculation of your original recursion and it matched.  The exponents arise because $$1-(1/2)^{-k}=[k]_{1/2}(1-1/2) = 2^{-1}[k]_{1/2}.$$ Because the product of the $1-q^k$ has $n$ such terms, that introduces a factor of $(1/2)^n=2^{-n}$ when re-expressing it in terms of the Gaussian Binomial coefficients.